# PowerShell not executing script from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a powershell script that I need to execute from a SQL server on a schedule. I don't think it matters, but in case it does, the script is sending the command to refresh a powerbi.com dataset. I can run it successfully locally and on one of my servers, but when I try it on the other one, I get the error below.

For clarification, the powershell versions match as well as the execution policies. I have listed them here:

**PS Version** 5.1.14409.1005

**Execution Policy**

```
Scope                ExecutionPolicy

Machine Policy       Undefined
User Policy          Undefined
Process              Undefined
CurrentUser          Undefined
LocalMachine         RemoteSigned
```

The error I get on one of the servers is below:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount : Failed to populate environments in settings
At
DatasetRefresh_NoParam_Simple.ps1:9
char:1
+ Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $myCred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...IServiceAccount:ConnectPowerBIServiceAccount) [Connect-Po
   werBIServiceAccount], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to populate environments in settings,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.ConnectPo
   werBIServiceAccount

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : Login first with Login-PowerBIServiceAccount
At
DatasetRefresh_NoParam_Simple.ps1:19
char:1
+ Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $RefreshDSURL -Method Post -Body $MailF ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod
```

I feel like there is a server setting that I'm missing, but I'm logged into both with admin credentials and running powershell as administrator. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

I tried to run a different script to also show the other error I am getting.

```
\\BlahServerName\WorkSpace\PowerBI\BDW_Resources\Admin\DatasetRefresh_PS\DatasetRefresh_Param_onlyDataset.ps1 : File
\\BlahServerName\WorkSpace\PowerBI\BDW_Resources\Admin\DatasetRefresh_PS\DatasetRefresh_Param_onlyDataset.ps1 cannot be
loaded. The file
\\BlahServerName\WorkSpace\PowerBI\BDW_Resources\Admin\DatasetRefresh_PS\DatasetRefresh_Param_onlyDataset.ps1 is not
digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and
setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ \\BlahServerName\WorkSpace\PowerBI\BDW_Resources\Admin\DatasetRefresh_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

This is the one I got too that led me to look at the execution policies, but if both of my servers have the same policy settings, why am I able to execute on one and not the other? (Again, I'm logged in as myself on both with admin privileges)

Comment: You’re not showing any of your code.

Comment: PowerShell comes in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors - each with their own collection of modules and settings. Are you using the correct PowerShell environment?

Comment: @DougMaurer, I didn't show any code because I'm not sure it is relevant to my issue. Invoking a PowerBI dataset refresh from PowerShell is well documented and mine doesn't contain anything extra. For reference, you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697381/power-bi-dataset-refresh-using-powershell for what mine mostly looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing it from SQL Server - I assume that is using SQL Agent?

Be aware of the context that SQL Server Agent executes in - have you created a SQL Agent Proxy using a defined credential to ensure the context?

Comment: I appreciate your comment. In this test, I was logged into the server as myself and attempting to run directly from PowerShell. Wouldn't need SQL Agent yet until I put this into a job.